# Azure Logic App - Parse JSON Schema fails "Required properties are missing from object"

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a table with 3 properties out of which only two properties have data in it. I have using SQL connector to get the data and then passing it into a "Parse JSON" module.

Following is the output of my SQL Connector:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://logic-apis-southeastasia.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/somethings/items",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "Some alpha-numeric id",
      "userEmail": "somename@blabla.com",
      "someCode": "someCode"
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

For the above output, my JSON Schema is as follows for "Values" tag:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "@@odata.etag": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ItemInternalId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "userEmail": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "someCode": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "@@odata.etag",
            "ItemInternalId",
            "userEmail",
            "someCode"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run my Logic App, I get the following error in the "Parse JSON" connector:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Required properties are missing from object: someCode.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "[318]",
    "value": [],
    "schemaId": "#/items",
    "errorType": "required",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]
```

Initially I had 4-5 data pointers in my table and the Parse JSON connector was working fine. I inserted few more records and now I am getting this error. I can't understand what could be the problem here..

Please help.

Comment: Can you remove the "required" part of your schema and try again, do you still get the error?

Comment: Aren't you generating the JSON Schema using the output of your SQL Connector?

Comment: Thanks @RickyG for your input, your solution worked.

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT I was generating the JSON Schema using the SQL Connector Output only, but it was still giving me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is down to your required tag.

```
{
"type": "array",
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.etag": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ItemInternalId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "userEmail": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "someCode": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Get rid of the required tag like above, or alternatively in your input pass something in your etag not just an empty string

```
"@odata.etag": "<dont leave this empty, pass something in>"
```